# Why does a project with product flavors not have the lintDebug task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I create an android project without product flavors and run `./gradlew tasks`, I can see there is a `lintDebug` task. When I add product flavors

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {...}

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".full"
            versionNameSuffix "-full"
        }
    }
    ...
```

And run `./gradlew tasks` again, I only see `lintDemoDebug` and `lintFullDebug`, there is no `lintDebug` command. But there is still an assembleDebug command which builds both product flavors.

Why is there no `lintDebug` command that lints both product flavors?

Edit: The same seems to be true of `testDebug`. Why is this?

Comment: Hey! @Matt, Did you find out why?

Comment: @kiranpuppala No I never did.

Comment: I'm also intrigued about this. The internet seems to be drawing a blank.